# How can I say "female soldier" in Japanese

Tags: word-choice, kanji

I have trouble translating "female soldier" in Japanese: Is it 女戦士 or 女性戦士? Also is the particle の lacking between the two words?

Comment: Excellent question. I really couldn't find anything beyond 女性戦士 which doesn't exactly sound ideal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what my boyfriend has to say (who is fluent in Japanese): 女性戦士 is more like female warrior, and female soldier would be 女性兵士. But depending on what you need it for, note that neither of them really sound cool.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Although can I know why it doesn't sound cool? It was an idea for a tattoo honestly 

Comment: Well, according to what he said (and note that I'm not at all qualified to judge this myself), it sounds mostly like a description of what it is, like words from the dictionary kinda. But he didn't really have a good alternative unfortunately. Oh, and it it is fine to not have a の I think. Also, a google image search should make the difference between 兵士 and 戦士 pretty clear.

Comment: I see ! Thanks again for your answers ! It's way more clear ^^